# Prevent rename of Azure Subscriptions without custom RBAC roles (possibly using Azure Policy)

Tags: azure, azure-policy

In Azure, users with the 'Owner' or 'Contributor' role assigned to a Subscription are able to rename it via the Portal. In order to enforce a consistent naming scheme, we would like to prevent subscription renames after they have been created.

This can be done with a custom RBAC role, but ideally we would like to avoid that. Can anyone suggest an alternative approach?

I had considered using an Azure Policy, and have tried the below:

```
"policyRule": {
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Subscription/SubscriptionDefinitions"
      },
      {
        "field": "Microsoft.Subscription/SubscriptionDefinitions/subscriptionDisplayName",
        "exists": "true"
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
  }
}
```

However, this seems to have no effect and a rename can still be carried out via the Portal or CLI.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also done some research to prevent users changing the subscription name.
This requires controlling the action `Microsoft.Subscription/rename/action`, in which `rename` is the resource type, and `action` the action.

You would expect that you can block this action using a policy with effect [DenyAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects#denyaction). However, this type of policy effect **currently** only allows actions named `delete`, and when you try to provide the action named as `action` above, the API denies such policy definition:

`The policy definition 'MyCustomPolicyName' rule is invalid. The 'actionNames' field in 'denyAction' effect details must be an array with a single value of 'delete'.`

This is also documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects#denyaction) in the introduction text of heading `DenyAction`.

Therefore, the only option left is to put the following action as a `NotAction` in a custom RBAC role and ensure that users are using that role.
`Microsoft.Subscription/rename/action`

I hope Azure will support more actions in the DenyAction effect soon.